# What is this tiny hitchhiker weed, and how can I kill it?

Tags: identification, weed-control

Can anyone identify this small, sticky weed?  The tips stick by the hundreds to shoes, socks, pets, or anything that goes through it.  My back yard got a small patch of it about a year or two ago, and now the entire back yard is practically covered with it!

If anyone can recommend a weed killer that will control this menace, I would appreciate it.

[image: Close-up of weed]
[image: Close-up of flower]
[image: Weed with context]

Comment: Can you add another picture which shows the foliage of the plant please?

Comment: @Bamboo I added another picture to better show the (practically microscopic) flower of the weed.  But there is no other foliage -- what I show in the top picture is pretty much the entire above-ground portion of the plant.  It's very small, but it's so pervasive that it's almost choked out my whole yard.

Comment: I'm not sure what this plant is - I thought maybe Galium aparene (common name sticky willy) but that does have a bit of foliage and the flowers only have 4 petals....

Comment: @Bamboo: this is a caryophyllaceae. But not one on my flora. @ Haydentech: where did you find such flower?

Comment: @Haydentech - can you add a photo showing a patch of this plant actually in situ - it might (or might not) help...

Comment: @Bamboo New pic added with the weed in context.  The round-leafed weed in the picture is a separate weed unrelated the one in the question.

Comment: @Haydentech did you find a solution? I have the same ones.

Comment: @RichardW11 I do now believe this is some form of chickweed, just a really low, ground-hugging variety that I can't find good data on.  I used a herbicide that specifically mentioned chickweed, and it had virtually no effect.  So no, I don't yet have a solution.  I'm considering getting some chickens, even just temporarily, to see if they can control it.

Comment: I would like to point out that in Southern California, this plant is one of the larval food plants for Arachnis picta, the painted tiger moth, a moth of the family Erebidae. The moth's forewings have lovely black & white abstract linear patterns, while the underwings are a beautiful shade of orange-red. The larva, a caterpillar known as a "woolly bear," because of the dense, bristly hair that covers their bodies. It is pretty cool. They commonly come out at night to feed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I will argue for Drymaria cordata, known as "Tropical chickweed." It is very closely related to Stellaria and Cerastium; Brisbane Australia City Council [has a go at teasing these apart](https://weeds.brisbane.qld.gov.au/weeds/tropical-chickweed); see the bottom of their document in the section "Similar species". Arguments in favour of Drymaria are the small leaves and relatively hairless stems, but most importantly it is a weed in St Augustine grass which makes it a tropical pest as opposed to temperate. Note that while all appear to have 10 petals in fact they all have 5 which are deeply lobed.

Comment: You were spot on. Thanks!

Comment: That page has the only pictures I've ever seen that somewhat accurately match what I have.  Mine never seem to grow the big leaves at any point in the year, but the picture of the younger stage is practically identical to what I have.

Answer (score 2):

I think that's chickweed (Stellaria media). It's an annual, so the best way to kill it is to hand-pull it before it sets seed. This is always easier said than done because there is always a ton of it in the lawn before you really notice it. An herbicide is relatively useless with chickweed, though, because although it may kill the plant, it will kill the plant only after its seeds have been spread throughout your lawn. Next year, you may be able to use an herbicide if you spot-spray it onto the plants as soon as you see them in the spring. This year, it's already too late for that.

Hand-pulling is always a multi-year task, unfortunately.

Comment: There's a better solution than hand pulling. Get some hens. It's called "chickweed" for a reason! They will search and destroy every last seed.

Comment: Well, it looks like chickens are legal in the OP's area, so that might work. Chickens aren't for everyone though - I personally do not like dealing with them (this is thanks to a friend who raises chickens for eggs and whose chickens I've been around enough times to know better). Darn little dinosaurs...

Comment: Stellaria media is almost harmless. It growth slow. It doesn't make much competition on water and nutrients. And easy to remove by hand: it expand a lot horizontally, but without roots (but on main section).

Comment: In any case, to me it doesn't seem a Stellaria media (lack of leaves), long steam. I think it is one of the similar plants: Cerastium and company.

Comment: While I appreciate your response, I agree with @GiacomoCatenazzi -- this is not chickweed.  My weed is much, much smaller and has no visible leaves at all, unlike the prominent leaves of chickweed.  What you see in my first picture is practically the whole, mature plant, not just a tip.  It's only a couple inches taller than the St. Augustine grass it's choking out.

Comment: @Jurp what about using chickens to kill it?

Comment: Haydentech - my chickweed is a very small plant that hugs the ground. I'm talking about Stellaria, not the other chickweed, which is much taller and has larger leaves: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/StellariaMedia001.JPG  as opposed to any of these: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_plants_known_as_chickweed.  Photos of the entire plant in your lawn would be an asset here, to guarantee a better identification.

Comment: @Jurp While I do think I have some form of chickweed, it seems to be an odd variety that never gets anywhere near the size of any chickweed I've seen pictured online, including your ground-hugging variety.  It's max leaf size at maturity is only roughly the size of the flower at the tip.  They make up for it with all the sticky buds though.

Comment: Well, there are somewhere between 90 and 120 different Stellaria species, so it could be a challenge to identify this one. The sticky buds make me more positive of my identification as a Stellaria of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

Let me just say, I have chickens and they get coated in these, just like my dogs do.  Actually kind of funny seeing their whole heads coated with them like a helmet.
Long story short, I have chickens and I have tons of this weed in my back yard.  So get your backyard chickens for the eggs, not for these weeds. :-)

Comment: Hello Peggy.  Thank you for contributing.   Do you have a name you call this plant?  common names are fine.  And take a moment to take a tour of the site https://gardening.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

These are not chickweed, they’re hitchhiker weed and unfortunately one of the only ways to truly cure them is to pull them out! They’re such a nuisance, I live in Florida and I have this scattered throughout my front lawn. My one year Shih Tzu mix gets COVERED in them and she hates being brushed so I have to pick them out of her hair. Very frustrating!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  You could improve your answer by posting a picture of your weed.